notify-send won't show up on generic X sessions, but works in a KDE session
I have Suse Tumbleweed, and sometimes I work in a KDE Plasma session on X, and in this case notify-send works as intended.
Othertimes I use icewm or compiz as my window managers, and in both cases notify-send does not work as intended, that is, no popup windows is shown (but no error condition is raised).
How can I have working notifications in every case?

I understand that my question is a bit sketchy, if you have any question I'll be happy to add further info.

You might need to install or start a notification daemon, of which there are many. This archlinux help suggests you need to explicitly start one, as .desktop files are ignored. The kde notification system might not like working outside kde.

@meuh Thank you very much, I installed a notification daemon (oh well, two of them)·and now I can do what I want with my notifications.

Thank you meuh, that in a comment showed me the solution to my problem.
I solved installing a notification daemon, oh well, two: notify-osd and dunst; and starting one of them from ~/.xinitrc.
If I start a daemon from the CLI and use notify-send from the CLI as well, I see a lot of warnings and some error message too, but it works anyway, and, of course, I don't see them if the scripts are used from the window manager using a shortcut.
I cited notify-osd and dunst, but you can find other notification daemons.

In retrospect, these lines from man notify-send
   -t, --expire-time=TIME
       The duration, in milliseconds, for the notification to appear on screen.

       Not all implementations use this parameter. GNOME Shell and Notify OSD
       always ignore it, while Plasma ignores it for notifications with the
       critical urgency level.

are indicating the need for some sort of server to display the notifications from clients.
